# Delete customer using id in node.js

Tags: node.js

i want to delet customer by id but i am getting error. thnks for the help

```
           app.get('/deleteCustomer/:customerID', function (req, res){

           var customerID = req.params.customerID;

            customer.delete({
                where:{
                    id:customerID
                },
                include:[mealRequirement, user]
            }).then(function(customers){
                //res.render('main.ejs', {page:"addCustomer", mrcats:mrcats, customer:customers[0], user:customers[0].user, authUser: req.isAuthenticated()});
            });

});
```

TypeError: customer.delete is not a function at Object.handle

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: for sequelize you can use destroy and for mongoose remove

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sequelize, you should use [destroy](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy) instead of delete.